# Fixtures won't load in Karma

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner, fixtures

I've been trying numerous things, but I can't seem to get an fixture to load when I run Karma. I've tried using `html2js` and `karma-jasmine-jquery`—I'm leaning toward the latter, but I'll be okay with whichever one gets my fixture loaded in the DOM)—but as far as I can tell it's not getting loaded and attached to the DOM when my tests run.

My directory structure is pretty simple:

```
img/
  ↳ mac.png
  ↳ link.png
  ↳ pocketwatch.png
js/
  ↳ spriteloader.js
  ↳ spriteloader.spec.js
karma/
  ↳ imagelist.fix.html
  ↳ karma.conf.js
Gruntfile.coffee
index.html
grunt.config.coffee
package.json
```

These are the node modules I've got installed:

```
grunt 0.4.5
grunt-contrib-jshint 0.10.0
grunt-contrib-watch 0.6.1
grunt-karma 0.9.0
karma 0.12.23
karma-chrome-launcher 0.1.4
karma-firefox-launcher 0.1.3
karma-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.0",
karma-jasmine 0.2.0
karma-jasmine-jquery 0.1.1
karma-safari-launcher 0.1.1
karma-story-reporter 0.2.2
```

And here's my `karma.conf.js` settings:

```
basePath: '../',

frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],

files: [
  // Source and spec files
  {
    pattern: 'js/*.js',
    watched: true,
    served: true,
    included: true
  },
  // Fixtures
  {
    pattern: 'karma/*.fix.html',
    watched: false,
    served: true,
    included: false
  }
],

exclude: [
],

preprocessors: {
},

reporters: ['story'],

port: 9018,

colors: true,

logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

autoWatch: true,

browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'Safari'],

singleRun: true
```

In my spec, I start off my `describe()` with a `beforeEach()` that runs the following two lines:

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = '../';
jasmine.getFixtures().load('/karma/imagelist.fix.html');
```

Then the `it()` functions start. They're testing a function that adds an event listener to some `<img>` elements using `document.getElementById()`. That's where the fixture needs to come in, because without it the `getElementById()` will return `null`. (Which is the issue I'm hitting.)

I've scoured the web for almost a full day looking for things to try, but I can't seem to get anything out of Karma other than `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`. I've tried changing my Karama config so that, instead of being empty, `preprocessors` has  `"**/*.html": []` in it to disable `html2js`, but that did nothing. I've tried disabling `jasmine-jquery` and using `html2js` instead, but there's barely any documentation on `karma-html2js-preprocessor`, so I can't even tell if I'm using it right. (Which is why I'm leaning more towards `jasmine-jquery`.) I just can't figure this one out.

**UPDATE (3 OCT)**

I found [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938580/how-do-you-serve-svg-and-fixtures-with-karma-runner-aka-testacular) and tried out the answer there, but it didn't work—I still got the same behaviour I've been seeing. My `karma.conf.js` is unchanged from above, but in my `spriteloader.spec.js` I changed the Jasmine calls to this:

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'http://localhost:9019/base/karma/';
jasmine.getFixtures().load('imagelist.fix.html');
```

I also tried this, and got the same result again:

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'http://localhost:9019/base/karma/';
jasmine.getFixtures().load('http://localhost:9019/base/karma/imagelist.fix.html');
```

I then found [this issue thread on GitHub](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/788) and changed `preprocessors` in `karma.conf.js` to this:

```
preprocessors: {
    '**/*.html': []
},
```

And I changed the Jasmine calls in my spec to this:

```
var fixtures = jasmine.getFixtures();
fixtures.fixturesPath = 'base/karma/';
fixtures.load('imagelist.fix.html');
```

This also resulted in the same behaviour: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

I also found [this post](https://coderwall.com/p/uvxnmq) and tried the configuration outlined in it—except for the addition of `JASMINE` and `JASMINE_ADAPTER` to the `files` section of `karma.conf.js`—but am still getting the same behaviour.

Since I have `karma-jasmine-jquery` installed locally, I pointed to the `jasmine-jquery` script like this:

```
'node_modules/karma-jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js'
```

I even tried ditching the Jasmine calls altogether and going with an AJAX call instead:

```
$('#fixture').remove();
$.ajax({
    async: false, // must be synchronous to guarantee that no tests are run before fixture is loaded
    dataType: 'html',
    url: '../karma/imagelist.fix.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('body').append($(data));
    }
});
```

I still got the same result, though. Not sure what else I can try.

**UPDATE (4 OCT)**

I found [this question/answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690005/why-is-karma-refusing-to-serve-my-json-fixture-which-id-like-to-use-in-my-jasm) and tried to set it up with `html2js` per the solution in there. I removed `jasmine-jquery` from the `frameworks` section of my `karma.conf.js`, and added a `plugins` section that looks like this:

```
plugins: [
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-firefox-launcher',
    'karma-html2js-preprocessor',
    'karma-jasmine',
    'karma-safari-launcher',
    'karma-story-reporter'
],
```

I also changed my `preprocessors` section to look like this:

```
preprocessors: {
    '**/*.html': ['html2js']
},
```

And I changed my `beforeEach()` to the following:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    var imagelist = __html__['../karma/imagelist.fix.html'];
    document.body.appendChild(imagelist);
});
```

I'm still seeing the same `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`, though.

Comment: THIS is how you question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use `karma-jasmine-jquery` you can just set the following:

1. add it as a framework - `frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine']`
2. include your fixtures as patterns under the files array - `{ pattern: 'test/fixtures/*.html', included: false, served: true }`
3. set the path using `base/` such as `jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/test/fixtures';` in your test suites.
4. load the fixtures into your test specs - `loadFixtures('index.html');`

karma-jasmine-jquery 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-jquery

Karma Config
http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/files.html

#### Update 02.16.16

Newer versions of Chrome don't allow file:// URIs read other file:// URIs. In effect, jasmine-jquery cannot properly load fixtures under some versions of Chrome. An override for this is to run Chrome with a switch `--allow-file-access-from-files`. https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#cross-domain-policy-problems-under-chrome

Comment: This is gold. I had a build process that I've moved from Grunt to Gulp and it was a real pain in the ass matching the functionalities. Finally when I reached the testing part (with Jasmine) I had problems setting up the fixtures. I used to include jasmine-jquery and jquery manually in the testRunner. Now everything works nice https://github.com/serbanghita/formToObject.js/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear @serbanghita. Cheers.

Comment: Also!! It's worth mentioning that I had to add `plugins : "karma-jasmine-jquery"` to get it to work. Thanks @cjroe

Answer (score 0):

**How to load JSON Fixture in Karma?**

**Step-1** Register json fixtures to **files** array inside **karma.conf.js**

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  files: [

     //load fixtures
      {
          pattern: 'tests/**/*.json',
          watched: true,
          served: true,
          included: false
      },

     //Other js/spec files go here

     'src/sample.test.js',
     'tests/sample.test.spec.js'

      ]
```

**Step-2** Loading **json fixture** inside describe in **sample.spec.js** file

```
describe('sample test suit', function () {     
let testFixture = {};
 //load test data fixture

beforeEach(function () {

    //loading fixtures data before each case
    jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/tests/fixtures';
    testFixture = getJSONFixture('test.testdata.json').key;        

});

it('should return test here', function () {

    expect(testFixture ).toBe({ data : 'some data' });

});
```

---

**How to load HTML Fixture in Karma?**

**Step-1** Create a HTMLfixture as follows (**test.dom.js** file)

```
function setUpHTMLFixture() {
    jasmine.getFixtures().set(' *********Email sender******** \
\
                                <div class="div3">  \
                                    <a id="sender-0"> \
\
                                             ********* removeIncomingAttachmentsFromTab ******** \
                                               <div id="newLineBR"></div> \
                                                <div class="sender-attachments"></div> \
                                                 <div class="attachmentiFramecls" style="margin-left:10px;"></div> \
                                             *********End removeIncomingAttachmentsFromTab ******** \
\
                                     </a> \
                                 </div> \
\
                                *********End email sender******** \
\
\
                                ********* createIFrameFormForPost ******** \
\
                                    <div id="iFrameFormForContainer"></div> \
\
                                *********End createIFrameFormForPost ******** \
\
\
                                ********* initEmailBody ******** \
\
                                    <div id="emailBody">Email Sending Test from test at 7/18/2018 8:06:56 AM \
                                                        hi, here is a a link http://testlabz.com/ \
                                                        This is an automated test email. \
                                                         Please do not reply</div> \
\
                                 ********* End initEmailBody ******** \
\
       ');
}
```

**Step-2** Register email fixture in karma config inside files array as follows:

```
  files: [
         //load fixtures
         "tests/fixtures/test.dom.js",
        //load spec file
        './tests/emailclient.spec.js',
        ]
```

**Step-2** Load HTMLFixture before each test case as follows:

```
  describe('htmlFixture test suit', function () {

     //load test dom fixture

      beforeEach(function () {

       //loading html fixtures data before each case
       setUpHTMLFixture();      
   });

   //test the element with here

     it("should text html", function () {       

       expect($("#emailBody")).toExist();

   });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding fixture to frameworks in the karma.conf.js file solved this issue for me. 
`frameworks: ['jasmine', 'fixture']`