# Is it possible to serve JSON files with Karma?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

I'm writing unit tests with karma. In my angular code I have this string:

```
$http.get('data/config.json');
```

JSON files are places in src/data folder. When I am running tests the script can't load this data.

Btw, I tried this in my karma.conf:

```
files: [
    ...    
    {pattern: 'src/data/*.json', watched: true, included: false, served: true}
],

proxies: {
   '/data/': 'src/data'
}
```

And after running tests:

```
24 09 2015 13:49:30.361:WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy src/data/config.json (socket hang up)
```

Comment: Try taking a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370427/loading-a-mock-json-file-within-karmaangularjs-test)

Comment: use $httpBackend for it. you will get it