# How to access json files from karma tests

Tags: json, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to create a test for my typescript class which reads data from a json file..

```
readData<T>(filePath: string): Promise<T> {
    return Qajax.getJSON(filePath);
}
```

I am using Jasmine and karma environment for testing. My issue is that even if I add any json files inside the karma, it won't be loaded in chrome launcher

```
    files: [
        'libs/angular/angular.js',
        'libs/angular/angular-route.js',
        'libs/angular/angular-mocks.js',            
        'libs/collections/collections.js',
        'tests/framework/common/app_config.json',
        'tests/package.json',

        { pattern: 'libs/qajax/qajax.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'libs/q/q.js', included: false },

        { pattern: 'tests/framework/**/*.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'tests/toolpattern/**/*.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'tests/test-main.js', included: true },

    ]
```

As you can see in the above karma config, I have added a file called app_config.json. Now I am trying to read that file from test...

```
it("read data test.", function (done) {

    var promise = configurationAccessorImpl.readData("tests/framework/common/app_config.json");
    promise.then(result => {
        console.info("Get configuration test - Success.");
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

});
```

The test always fails as the json file does not exists..

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370427/loading-a-mock-json-file-within-karmaangularjs-test) has better answers

Answer (score 1):

Library jasmine-jquery provides couple of extensions for the Jasmine JavaScript Testing Framework.
Used the extension API for handling HTML, CSS, and JSON fixtures in test specs, to read the .json file.

Steps:
- add jasmine-jquery.js  to libs & jasmine-jquery.d.ts to / libs/typings
, add required references in karma.config to the libs, add JSON fixture location to read the files from:

```
   // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
   …………………………..
        'libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js',
        'libs/jasmine-jquery/jasmine-jquery.js',
   ………………….
          // JSON fixture
        {
            pattern: 'configuration/*.json',
            watched: true,
            served: true,
            included: false
        }
    ],
```

- now in karma test, can read the file as follows:

```
 /// <reference path="../../../libs/typings/jasmine-jquery/jasmine-jquery.d.ts" />  
  ……………………    
/**
 *  @description Unit test for - Getting the configuration file in karma.     
 */
it("Configuration file accessor: Read configuration file test.", function (done) {

    jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/configuration/';

    var jsonData = getJSONFixture('app_config.json');
    var appConfig = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

   // Prints the config file content
    console.info(appConfig);
    expect(appConfig).toBeDefined();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the function configurationAccessorImpl.readData does. But if you're trying to load the JSON file using an HTTP request, you might be having a problem with the fact that karma serves test files from a /base relative path.

Try and change your test to:

```
var promise = configurationAccessorImpl.readData("/base/tests/framework/common/app_config.json");
```

It might do the job.

Comment: The main issue here is that json files are not getting loaded in karma environment. When you check the source files from Chrome launcher, you  can't see the file "/base/tests/framework/common/app_config.json".. All other .js files are visible..